# Which oxygen is favored for protonation when hydrolysis of an acetal occurs?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

My question is about which oxygen is favored for protonation in acidic conditions. So, R1 and R2 are different in the following diagram (for example, one is propyl but the other is ethyl). I looked up my organic chemistry materials, but only symmetric cases (R1 = R2) were suggested.

[image]

I believe that there will be a competition between two pathways, and it is related to the stability of intermediate in the reaction mechanism. But how can I estimate which pathway is favored or the stability of the intermediates?

[image]

Comment: I don't see a practical application of this concept, all acetals that I could find were those where R1 = R2 since it's part of a reaction that happens in one media.

Comment: @SafdarFaisal I see why the symmetric case is common, though I can also find articles about a synthesis of unsymmetric acetals.

Comment: A somewhat complex example is a glycosidic bond, for example a 1,4 linkage between two glucose molecules. The "1" position involved in the bond is then an acetal with two very different substituents.

Comment: Possible dupe? Its a specific case but still..https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/18588/hydrolysis-of-cyclic-acetal?rq=1